# USB hub not working after boot

Tags: usb, hub

I have strange problem with USB hub manufactured by LC Technology with chip GL850G.
When I power on the raspberry, hub doesn't seem to work (LED is off), but when I disconnect hub from port and hot-plug it back to the port, it magically starts working.

How to make it start automatically?

Comment: Is this a powered hub? How are you powering the Pi and Hub?

Comment: Raspberry is powered by 700mA smartphone charger through USB micro port. Here's hub specification: http://www.lctech-inc.com/Hardware/Detail.aspx?id=ebab70c9-8353-4b18-8b3d-3fc2f8f909bd

Comment: I would try  another charger for your Pi. 700 mA is the the specified minimum requirement of a (1st gen Pi, model 2's require even more power) if your charger is off even a little it can cause all kinds of problems. Also you hub looks like it is powered by the Pi - you should try a powered hub. This could explain the behavior you are seeing - since the Pi will demand more energy on startup.