# Building RAID fails

Tags: pi-4, power, raid, dietpi

I try to set up a RAID1 on a RPi4 with mdadm.
I struggled at various corners along the way. Since it still doesn't work, I'm not sure what's fixed and what's still causing problems.

## Equipment

- Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1
- OS: Dietpi v8.20.1
- USB - SATA Adapter: [Delock 61883](https://www.delock.com/produkt/61883/merkmale.html)
- USB Hub: [LOGILINK PA0139](https://www.tme.eu/ch/en/details/pa0139/desktop-power-supplies/logilink/)
- Two SSD: Samsung EVO 750 250GB

## USB-SATA Adapter

```shell
root@DietPi:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge
```

As the USB-SATA Adapter is somehow not recognized by default, I added `usb-storage.quirks=174c:55aa:u` to `/boot/cmdline.txt`
This seems to work. The Disc are getting recognized now.

```
root@DietPi:~# dmesg
[    0.676490] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 6.01
[    0.676504] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.676515] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.676524] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 6.1.21-v8+ xhci-hcd
[    0.676533] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    0.676867] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.676905] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    0.677343] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 6.01
[    0.677358] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.677368] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.677377] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 6.1.21-v8+ xhci-hcd
[    0.677386] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    0.677707] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.677773] hub 2-0:1.0: 4 ports detected

[    0.929512] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.079868] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=3431, bcdDevice= 4.21
[    1.079902] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    1.079914] usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[    1.081141] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.081456] hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    1.205873] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.227040] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    1.227075] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[    1.227086] usb 2-1: Product: ASMT1051
[    1.227095] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: asmedia
[    1.227104] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 123456789012
[    1.229057] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    1.229418] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 55aa: c00000
[    1.229556] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[    1.357918] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.378876] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    1.378909] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[    1.378920] usb 2-2: Product: ASMT1051
[    1.378928] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: asmedia
[    1.378937] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 123456789012
[    1.381052] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    1.381361] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 55aa: c00000

[    2.238326] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ASMT     2105             0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[    2.239491] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 488397168 512-byte logical blocks: (250 GB/233 GiB)
[    2.240044] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    2.240055] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[    2.240652] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    2.268616]  sda:
[    2.268768] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk

[    2.398137] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ASMT     2105             0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[    2.399051] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 488397168 512-byte logical blocks: (250 GB/233 GiB)
[    2.399652] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    2.399669] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[    2.400260] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    2.409996]  sdb:
[    2.410145] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[    2.707962] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    2.713195] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
```

## USB Hub

The SSD's are connected to the RPi via USB3. This is enough to recognize the discs in the system. Actually the plan was to supply the SSD's with additional power via USB2 connectors of the USB-SATA adapter connected to the USB-HUB. However, if the discs are connected to the USB hub, I can unplug the primary USB-C power supply on the RPi and it keeps running. It seems that the RPi is powered by the disc..
Also, the discs are no longer recognized after rebooting the RPi. I have to unplug the USB2 adapters at the USB HUB when rebooting the RPi so they are available in the system similar as described here: [Usb hub devices not recognized after reboot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69657/usb-hub-devices-not-recognized-after-reboot?newreg=0ef3d51755e64745846a65ccdb6f01cc)
As an alternative I've tried some simple USB Travel adapters with 1.0A Output. The Result was the same.
I could not find a solution for this problem and therefore I do not use an additional powersupply for the Disc's anymore.

## Setup RAID with mdadm

Starting the RAID with `mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda /dev/sdb` works for some seconds Then I see:

```
root@DietPi:~# dmesg

[  222.330459] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  257.146454] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  287.866458] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  320.634466] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  351.354403] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  386.170470] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  416.890447] usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  569.832188] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[  569.832246] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=183s
[  569.832266] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x2 [current] 
[  569.832282] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 ASC=0x4 ASCQ=0x1 
[  569.832301] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 09 73 80 00 02 00 00
[  569.832318] I/O error, dev sda, sector 619392 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x4000 phys_seg 36 prio class 2
```

## Help wanted

I'm totaly stucked with this. Every help/hint is highly appreciated!
This are my questions:

- Are the USB-Adapter's working correctly?
- Is the RPi/Disc's suffering from undervoltage?
- Is this USB-HUB any good? Do I have to configure something in the OS to use the USB-HUB as powersupply for the Disc's?
- Do the Disc's causing the Problems?

## Update

- When plugin the USB-SATA Adapters on the USB2-Port, it all works fine. Eventough `lsusb -t` shows the Adapters are not [connected with UASP](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2020/uasp-makes-raspberry-pi-4-disk-io-50-faster):

```shell
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
```